# Continuous border across multiple elements

Tags: css, border, line-numbers, css-counter

I am trying to add line numbers to a code snippet. It's working, except for the cosmetic detail that the border between the line number and the line of code isn't continuous. It has small, ugly gaps instead.

Inspect element doesn't seem to explain the spacing.

I have also tried fiddling with `line-height`, but nothing really worked without significantly affecting the spacing.

```css
pre {
    counter-reset: linenum;
    font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono";
}

pre code {
    counter-increment: linenum;
}

pre code::before {
    content: counter(linenum);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    color: #888;
    border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one</code>
<code>Line two</code>
<code>Line three</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: adding `line-height:0.8` to pre and `line-height:1` to code will fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `font-family` set in `pre`, so simple fix is removing the font, which will default to `monospace`

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: linenum;
}

pre code {
  counter-increment: linenum;
}

pre code::before {
  content: counter(linenum);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one</code>
<code>Line two</code>
<code>Line three</code>
</pre>
```

If you want to keep the font then you have a few approaches to achieve what you want:

- Set `display: grid` in the `pre`

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: linenum;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono";
  display: grid;
}

pre code {
  counter-increment: linenum;
}

pre code::before {
  content: counter(linenum);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one</code>
<code>Line two</code>
<code>Line three</code>
</pre>
```

- Set `display: flex` & `flex-direction: columnm` in the `pre`

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: linenum;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono";
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

pre code {
  counter-increment: linenum;
}

pre code::before {
  content: counter(linenum);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one</code>
<code>Line two</code>
<code>Line three</code>
</pre>
```

- Set `display: table-row` in the `code`

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: linenum;
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono";
  /*just be coeherent with table-row in the child */
  display: table
}

pre code {
  counter-increment: linenum;
  display: table-row
}

pre code::before {
  content: counter(linenum);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #888;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Line one</code>
<code>Line two</code>
<code>Line three</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you! Where can I read more about *why* this works?

Comment: It is actually caused by the `font-family` that you have in the `pre` tag. I've updated the answer to mention this